# Can Transformers be used on 3D arrays of data such as multivariate timeseries?

Tags: multidimensional-array, huggingface-transformers, multivariate-time-series

Can transformers be used on multivariate timeseries data, which is typically a 3D array with number of samples or subjects, number of timesteps, and number of variables?

I have read a few sources with conflicting information.

Comment: In principle, if we were to use a k-by-k matrix to represent each time step, the queries, keys, and values would be matrices as well. Perhaps we can pass each output matrix through an MLP (or a CNN in this case). This paper classifies videos using transformers and is cited well - ViViT: A Video Vision Transformer https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15691
Moreover, perhaps AI Stack Exchange is a better community for this question.